How to reason what the compiler might generate?
Background:
I am writing SGEMM and the performance was bad. Look at the disassembly and perf I found instructions like this:
...
| Time | Instruction                                      
|------|------------------------------------------------- 
| 0.46 | vmovaps ymm3,YMMWORD PTR [rdx]                   
| 2.13 | vmovaps ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rdx+0x20]              
| 0.16 | add rax,0x40                                     
| 0.16 | add rdx,0x40                                     
| 0.76 | vbroadcastss ymm2,DWORD PTR [rsi]                
| 0.36 | vbroadcastss ymm1,DWORD PTR [r15]                
| 0.56 | vbroadcastss ymm7,DWORD PTR [r14]                
| 0.10 | vmovaps ymm5,ymm3                                
| 0.52 | vmovaps ymm13,ymm3                               
| 0.22 | vbroadcastss ymm4,DWORD PTR [r13+0x0]            
| 2.42 | vfmadd213ps ymm13,ymm1,YMMWORD PTR [rax+0x1fc0]  
| 0.40 | vfmadd213ps ymm5,ymm2,YMMWORD PTR [rax-0x40]     
| 0.42 | vmovaps ymm9,ymm3                                
| 17.12| vfmadd213ps ymm2,ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rax-0x20]      <--
| 16.73| vfmadd213ps ymm1,ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rax+0x1fe0]    <--
...

Note that the last two fma takes up 30+% of the running time. My assumption is that these two instructions are slow due to the memory operand in them. Other fma in the assembly are way faster.
I've tried with different way of writing this program. Sometimes, the compiler generates fma with three operand being ymm registers while other times it generates fma with memory operand.
Is there any way to reason about the code generation or is it purely a myth? Also, is there anyway to force the compiler to generate code with three ymm registers without writing inline assembly code? Intrinsic doesn't seems to help with that.
Code to the implementation
CPU: i5-6200u (should probably get a better one)
Compiler: gcc version 14.0.1 20240413 (experimental) (GCC)
Optimization flags:  g++ -O3 -march=native -ffast-math  gemm.cpp -std=gnu++2a
UPD 0: added compiler information etc.
UPD 1: Change error in link

FWIW back when I undertook a similar project, I had to resort to writing the main kernel (not the block management around it and so on) in assembly after getting repeatedly trolled by arbitrary codegen decision that the compiler kept making.

Generally any good compiler will try to fold a load into a memory source operand for an ALU instruction if the load result is only used once.  This saves front-end (decode and issue/rename) bandwidth since the load + FMA uops can stay micro-fused in most of the pipeline other than the scheduler and execution units.
If you're cache-blocking so the same vectors of row data get re-used with multiple broadcasted columns, you'd expect the compiler to load once into a register.
If there aren't enough registers available, it might favour reloading this way, instead of spilling/reloading a variable needed later which would increase the length of a dependency chain.

You haven't mentioned a language, but in GNU C you could use asm("" : "+x"(foo)) as a black-box for the optimizer to force the __m256 variable foo to be in a register, with the "+" telling the compiler that it's modified by your asm template (which is the empty string, zero asm instructions).
But even if you force the compiler to do a separate vmovups load, your vfmadd instructions will still get the blame (from hardware performance counters like cpu_clk_unhalted.thread on my Skylake  (which Linux perf will use for the cycles event on CPUs that have that event).  The HW PMU typically "blames" the instruction that was waiting for the slow result, not the instruction that was slow to produce it.  (It has to pick one out of many that were in flight when the event counter rolled over.)
A well-tuned SGEMM should bottleneck on FMA execution-unit throughput, not memory, even for large matrices that don't all fit in L1d or L2 cache.  This isn't easy to achieve.
So I guess you're trying to see whether it's the load or the actual FMA that's slow?  Check how close you're coming to 2 FMA instructions per clock, or how much of the time the appropriate ports are busy vs. idle.  On Intel, uops_dispatched_port.port_0 and uops_dispatched_port.port_1 for 256-bit FMAs.  Check https://uops.info/ for  port number details.

The loaded result were used multiple times. To be more specific, the asm code generated from a program where that specific memory operand gets used 4 times. As you can imagine, for SGEMM C = AB, that memory operand was a segment of A (and all broadcasts comes from B).  But no, the compiler disrespects that (even though sometimes it does!).
I just tried the asm method you mentioned. The generated code are different this time, but I can still see some fma instruction with memory operand.

@gxu: Ok that makes sense; I guess you omitted the rest of the loop body where it's used again?   But which compiler / version with what options?  IIRC, GCC had that missed-optimization bug at one point, but google isn't finding the bugzilla bug report for me.

Is there any way besides writing asm in my code to force the compiler to generate code with register operands? I am writing C++, but C is also fine. And still, even if I used your method (the asm +x one), I still cannot determine what kind of code it will generate (I've designed my code in a way that all data I used can be fit into the registers).
Though should good implementations of SGEMM bottleneck on FMA? I always thought mov is slower than arithmetic. fma with three operand being ymm registers take at least 8 clock cycles to prepare, and yet fma can finish in 5 cycles.

@gxu: Not for mainstream compilers like GCC and Clang.  Maybe some compilers exist where there's an option to treat x86 like a load/store machine and avoid memory source operands for ALU instructions.  You still haven't said anything about what you're using.  If you link a [mcve] on https://godbolt.org/, we can play with optimization options and compiler versions.

@gxu: CPUs are pipelined!  Load latency overlaps with the latency of the previous FMAs, which all overlap with each other across loop iterations to keep at 8 FMAs in flight.  (On a CPU like Skylake with 4 cycle latency, 2/clock throughput: Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators) - in a dot product, FP add latency is loop-carried; it's important to unroll to deal with it).

@gxu:  See Latency bounds and throughput bounds for processors for operations that must occur in sequence re: latency and dependency chains.

Yes I omitted the loop body as I thought it is too long for a post. I will try to add it in. Compiler version: gcc version 14.0.1 20240413 (experimental) (GCC). CPU: i5-6200u.
Compiler flags: g++ -O3 -march=native -ffast-math  gemm.cpp -o gemm -std=gnu++2a. Is it possible that my cpu doesn't really support AVX2? I've heard that old cpu translate ymm instructions to xmm instructions internally while executing code?

AMD Zen 1 and earlier decoded 256-bit instructions as 2 uops for their 128-bit execution units.  Intel has only done that for E cores in Alder Lake.  Your CPU is Intel Skylake, only P cores. Its execution units are 256-bit wide.  If a CPU really didn't support AVX2, you'd get an illegal-instruction fault (or GCC -march=native wouldn't compile intrinsics for them, and wouldn't use them when auto-vectorizing).  Also, your code doesn't use any AVX2 instructions, just AVX1 and FMA.  AVX2 is 256-bit SIMD-integer and lane-crossing shuffles (including vbroadcastps ymm, xmm instead of mem src)

I understand that CPUs are pipelined. I might have misunderstanding on how to calculate latency and throughput. The calculation goes like this: 1 fma takes three ymm registers operand. Those operands needs to be broadcasted/loaded from memory. Now load/broadcast have .5 CPI, which means you can do 14 load/broadcast between the first load and the first fma. So even if you pipeline load and broadcast as much as possible, the first fma would still have to wait for 1 or 2 cycles to begin.

@gxu: CPUs also do out-of-order exec!  See the Instruction Scheduling, Register Renaming & OOO. section in https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ .  Also https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/ is a good deep-dive into some details of how out-of-order (OoO) exec happens; Haswell and Skylake are pretty similar pipelines, Skylake just makes some structures bigger and makes a few changes to what execution unit is on which port, so that article is still highly relevant to understanding your own CPU.  See also https://agner.org/optimize/.

Okay I just found out that I made a mistake: I tried to load more than 16 sets of numbers into registers. That of course will not work as there are only 16 ymms. I change the number so that in a loop I use only 14 ymm register with your method, all fmas have three registers operand. Yet the result is still slow. I will look into the articles you provided and put the implementation up ASAP. Many thanks.

I've put the code on godbolt, perhaps it is not minimal enough, but I putted bunch of comment on it. Hope it will help. https://godbolt.org/z/fW66TfrxP
